# Select all values of one column, sorted by another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table `stats` with columns `id`, `totalJumps`, `totalScore`, `topScore`, and `topScoreMod`. I wish to select all `id` values and sort them by `totalScore` in descending fashion.

I have tried `"SELECT id FROM stats ORDER BY totalScore DESC"` but this gives me only one `id` result.

EDIT: My apologies, I have updated the question to be more accurate. This issue is likely with PHP, not with the SQL. The MySQLi query returns all 3 `id` values in the correct order, but the PHP statement `$scoresRow = $scoresResult->fetch_array()`, where `$scoresResult` is the above MySQLi query, returns an array with 2 values according to `count($scoresRow)`, with `$scoresRow[0]` being `1` and `$scoresRow[1]` giving me the error `Undefined offset: 1`.

Comment: Your query should be correct.

Comment: How are you getting the results of the query? And does the table have more than one row in it?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question to be more accurate. This issue is likely with PHP, not with the SQL. The SQL query returns all 3 `id` values in the correct order, but the PHP statement `$scoresRow = $scoresResult->fetch_array()`, where `$scoresResult` is the above SQL statement, returns an array with 2 values according to `count($scoresRow)`, with `$scoresRow[0]` being `1` and `$scoresRow[1]` giving me the error `Undefined offset: 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using PDO extension? It ships with PHP and is the recommended library/extension to query the database. Follow instructions here 
 - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php - to ensure that it's enabled.

Then you should be able to do something like this in PHP:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM stats ORDER BY totalScore DESC");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['id']."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: I have considered switching to PDO in the past, but as per your suggestion I will look into it a bit more. I don't usually have issues with MySQLi and PHP, but this one has me a little stumped.

Comment: @RandallArms - You should, It'll make your life a whole lot easier esp. with more complex queries.

Answer (score 2):

the query you have written is correct, it should show you all the id from your table on a desc order based on totalScore. may i know how many data you have on your table?
have you done, select * from stats order by totalscore desc? how many records shows up?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question to be more accurate. This issue is likely with PHP, not with the SQL. The SQL query returns all 3 `id` values in the correct order, but the PHP statement `$scoresRow = $scoresResult->fetch_array()`, where `$scoresResult` is the above SQL statement, returns an array with 2 values according to `count($scoresRow)`, with `$scoresRow[0]` being `1` and `$scoresRow[1]` giving me the error `Undefined offset: 1`.